# PHP MYSQL CRUD(Create Read Update Delete) Application update error

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on a PHP MYSQL CRUD(Create Read Update Delete) Application however I am stuck at the update-(edit.php) script, the error messages are reflected in the following lines:     `if($_POST["do"]=="update")` stating: `undefined index 'do'` also I am getting this error message: `mysqli_query() expects 2 parameters` reffering back to:     `$result=mysqli_query($query);` and another similar stating `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`, referring back to:     `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))`
I have been trying to solve it for the past 2 days Im wondering if a few extra pair of eyes along with your knowledge could help me pin point the error(s).

```
<?php

if($_POST["do"]=="update"){

     $terminal=$_POST["terminal"];
     $acquirer=$_POST["acquirer"];
     $acquirer_name=$_POST["acquirer_name"];
     $acquirer_agent=$_POST["acquirer_agent"];
     $merchant_name=$_POST["merchant_name"];
     $multilink_terminal=$_POST["multilink_terminal"];
     $country=$_POST["country"];
     $parish=$_POST["parish"];
     $area=$_POST["area"];
     $location=$_POST["location"];
     $venue=$_POST["venue"];
     $status=$_POST["status"];
     $date_online=$_POST["date_online"];

$query="update terminal_ncb_jan_jun   set    
                                            acquirer='$acquirer',
                                             acquirer_name='$acquirer_name',
                                             acquirer_agent='$acquirer_agent',
                                             merchant_name='$merchant_name',
                                             multilink_terminal='$multilink_terminal',
                                             country='$country',
                                             parish='$parish',
                                             area='$area',
                                             location='$location',
                                             venue='$venue',
                                             status='$status',
                                             date_online='$date_online'

                                             where terminal=$terminal";

mysqli_query($query);
}




$terminal=$_GET["terminal"];

$query="select * from terminal_ncb_jan_jun where terminal='$terminal'";

$result=mysqli_query($query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>



<form name="update" method = "post" action ="edit.php">


<table>
<tr>
<td>Terminal</td>
<td><?php echo $row[0];?><input type="hidden" name="terminal" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"></td>

<td>Acquirer Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="acquirer_name" value="<?php echo $row[1];?>" disabled="disabled"></td>

<td>Acquirer Agent</td>
<td><input type="text" name="acquirer_agent" value="<?php echo $row[2];?>"></td>

<td>Merchant Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="merchant_name" value="<?php echo $row[3];?>"> </td>

<td>MultiLink Terminal</td>
<td><input type="text" name="multilink_terminal" value="<?php echo $row[4];?>"> </td>

<td>Country</td>
<td><input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $row[5];?>"></td>

<td>Parish</td>
<td><input type="text" name="parish" value="<?php echo $row[6];?>"></td>

<td>Area</td>
<td><input type="text" name="area" value="<?php echo $row[7];?>"></td>

<td>Location</td>
<td><input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $row[8];?>"></td>

<td>Venue</td>
<td><input type="text" name="venue" value="<?php echo $row[9];?>"></td>

<td>Status</td>
<td><input type="text" name="status" value="<?php echo $row[10];?>"></td>

<td>Date Online</td>
<td><input type="text" name="date_online" value="<?php echo $row[11];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name ='do' value ='update'><input type='submit' value="UPDATAE RECORD"></td>
</tr>



<?php } ?>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing `if($_POST["do"]=="update")` to 
`if(isset($_POST["do"] && $_POST["do"]=="update"))` and if `$terminal` is a string, then you will need to change that to `where terminal='$terminal'";` because that's what you've done for `"select * from terminal_ncb_jan_jun where terminal='$terminal'";`

Comment: However, I would recommend you name your submit button `<input type='submit' value="UPDATAE RECORD" name="submit">` and use `if(isset($_POST["submit"])){...}` instead of `if($_POST["do"]=="update")` you can try both methods.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` - Plus, `mysqli_query($query);` that needs to use a DB connection. I.e.: `mysqli_query($con,$query);` same thing for `$result=mysqli_query($query);` which is why your query is failing. No DB connection parameter. `$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);` replacing `$con`, with your DB variable. Had you been checking for DB (query) error, it would have caught that.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I guess I can scrap all of my comments lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- You have always been helpful and No please don't scrap the comment I will continue working on this current application as well as use the PDO and as always I am thankful

Comment: You're welcome. All of those will surely get you started and do use error reporting and DB query error checking. Those will help you along the way to debug your code. I think you will soon find success, *I can feel it* ;) @dames Be sure to use prepared statements. Just PDO on its own doesn't safeguard against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that $_POST['do'] doesn't have a value and so isn't instanced for your if.  Check its being passed to your update page correctly and that it has a value by simply echoing it out before the if.  Fix it.

2nd issue about mysql params is that you're not actually opening your mysql connection anywhere in your script so it can't run mysql_query.

Fixing issue 2 will fix all your other issues too.

Finally since it appears your just learning don't use mysql_ functions use PDO or at very least mysqli and prepared statements.

Comment: thanks for the pointers honestly as you made mention about using PDO, which I know is way better and the way to go I think I will put a pause on this project and switch to using PDO.

Comment: also use strcmp() function to compare strings

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken the original is using `mysqli`.

Comment: @dames If you're going to retool this, and it is rather disorganized and worth doing, the best plan is to find a
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that fits your style and needs and use that as a foundation for your application. It'll give you a better pattern to use for implementing and tends to lead to a far better organized code-base.

Comment: *"Finally since it appears your just learning don't use `mysql_` functions"* - Ditto on what Tadman said. OP doesn't have `mysql_` where did you see that or gotten that impression from?

Comment: @tadman yeah my mistake but still ! using prepared statements so still vulnerable just like mysql_ also don't recommend frameworks to newbies just starting better they learn the basics of good code before getting lost in frameworks.  Especially horrible ones like laravel

Comment: @dave Frameworks are the **best** place to start when you're learning how to build applications, and if you dislike Laravel, there are others. Starting with super low-level PHP is an excruciating way to get things done and the resulting code is a complete disaster. Separation of Model, View and Controller concerns is not something impossible to learn.

Comment: its not impossible to learn but every framework is horrible at it pretty much all the "big" ones teach you bad coding practices and hide alot of the under lying functions of the language in badly written helper functions.  You should always learn good coding theory and the underlying language first then start looking at frameworks to make your life easier once you have a firm grasp. Going straight to frameworks makes you useless and limited to only working with that framework otherwise you have to re-learn for a different one. Bad practice.